# Azure Data Factory send email on pipeline failure with Batch Service

Tags: azure-data-factory, sendmail

I want so send an email if a pipeline fails. I can see tutorial using Logic Apps but for the moment I cannot use that service.
I have searched for any other tutorial, but it looks like most of them use Logic Apps.
Can you help me with some tutorial using Batch Service or any other service?

Comment: Logic Apps is mostly used for this, you can try calling the MS Graph API in your pipeline and send a mail that way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Azure Functions would be another preferred option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an alternative to Logic Apps, you can use Azure Data Factory Alerts and Metrics.

Below are the Steps to configure this.
Go to the Monitor Tab in your Azure Data factory.

In the monitor tab at the bottom left side you will see ALERTS & METRICS

Create a New Alert Rule

[image]
Provide the name to your Alert name and the Severity of the failed Pipeline.

[image]
Add the target Criteria in the add Criteria look for the **'Failed pipeline runs metrics'**

[image]

[image]

Once the Criteria is added you will find the Dimension & Value. Dimension will be your Pipeline's and Values failure type. And click on **Add Criteria.**

[image]

Next you will see Configure Email/SMS/Push/Voice notification. Configure notification.

[image]
Create Action group name, short name and Add Notification.
[image]
Provide the action name select the type as email and provide your email address then click add notification.

[image]
Once you create Action group name you will receive email confirmation that you are added to Action group.
[image]
Now click **create Alert Rule**.
Once you create Alert rule and the pipeline fails It will trigger the  email to you inbox like below
[image]

Upon following the above steps you can configure Alert for your Azure Data factory Pipeline failures and receive email alerts.

***Note: The email alerts will only work for Triggered Runs not for the De-bug runs***

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a temporary solution that I will implement