# Azure Synapse data via API

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We would like to build an integration between Azure Synapse analytics and a marketing automation platform. The use case is basically to create a list of purchasers based on data already integrated in Azure Synapse and then send them an email using the marketing email platform.

I understand how to push the data to the marketing automation platform using the available APIs for that tool but not clear on how I would extract the data from Azure Synapse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Integrating data from Azure Synapse

Comment: Do want to extract the data from Azure synapse? also can you confirm where data needs to moved?

Comment: what approach have you followed so far?

Comment: hello, the data needs to be move to Salesforce.  This is fairly new for us, we do not have an approach yet.

Comment: ok sure let me try this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you want set up  integration between Azure Synapse analytics and a salesforce marketing platform
You can follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Create a linked service  and a source dataset for your Azure synapse(Source)
[image]
You can get the server name from synapse overview like below
[image]

[image]

**Step 2:**
Search for Salesforce and select the Salesforce connector. and Configure the service details, test the connection, and create the new linked service.
[image]

[image]

Know more about [Copy data from and to Salesforce using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory)

Also as you mentioned that you want send an email using the Once data is moved from marketing cloud from synapse.
You can refer the below similar [Azure Data Factory send email on pipeline failure with Batch Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76620753/azure-data-factory-send-email-on-pipeline-failure-with-batch-service/76628908#76628908)